# Linux slackware 13 automatically lock, ktorrent start automatically

Tags: linux, x-windows, slackware, ktorrent

Can someone tell me what to do for lock automatically slackware 13 if not used for n minutes ?

What can i do to start automatically the ktorrent (a bittorrent program for linux) on system starts on slackware 13 ?

Comment: This is two questions, they should be posted separately.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using X11, and you want to use `xlockmore`, the lightest-weight screen locker I've found, you can download and install `xautolock` and then add the following to your `.xinitrc`:

```
# start the auto-locker (defaults to 10 minutes)
xautolock &

[...]
# start the window manager of my choice
#exec /usr/bin/fluxbox
#exec /usr/bin/blackbox
exec /usr/bin/foo_window_manager
```

It's a traditional GNU/Linux app, so the settings are in ~/.Xdefaults. See man page.

Answer (score 0):

1. I don't see what's the point of automated locking. Is it so hard to start xlock manually when you are going AFK? If you have a specific scenario, please provide more details why this won't work for you.
2. ktorrent is a GUI app, so having it to start when system starts is probably wrong. I don't think it will run if no X server at least is running yet. I you want a bittorrent client that would always run in the background, pick one without GUI. I suggest rtorrent. Doesn't come with Slackware, but you could build it yourself (there's a SlackBuild for it at [slackbuilds.org](http://slackbuilds.org/))

Answer (score 0):

Slackware's default desktop is KDE and it can lock the screen after `X` minutes: `SystemSettings > Display > Screen Saver`.

Ktorrent can be made to start on KDE start by using either Session Management or adding Ktorrent to your list of Autostart programs. Both of these can be set in `SystemSettings > Startup and Shutdown`.